# Changing Dictionary key (kinda). What happens to the memory of the old key's value?

Tags: c#, dictionary, memory

I am wondering what happens behind the code. How is memory allocated when key gets changed. Does the memory of the old key's value get deleted (freed) and a new memory is allocated OR the same memory is used for the value of the new key. Basically I have this code:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<int, chunk> kvp in dDict)
{
    dDict[pList.Last()] = kvp.Value; // Adding new key/value pair THAT holds the value of the old key
    pList.Remove(pList.Last()); // Removing item from list, as it has been addressed here and not needed anymore
    dDict.Remove(kvp.Key); // Deleting old key/value pair from the dictionary
}
```

Now my question is:
Is `dDict[pList.Last()] = kvp.Value` pointing to the memory that is held by the old deleted key's value even after `dDict.Remove(kvp.Key);` is executed. Or is it holding a new memory block with copied value.

I tried looking it up online but didnt find definite answer

Comment: Well, in this case it's hard to argue that memory could be reused since you add the new key before deleting the old one, but in general you should not need to worry about this level of detail: memory will get freed or reused as appropriate.

Comment: So basically      dDict[pList.Last()] = kvp.Value     would not be pointing to the same memory that     kvp.Value     is pointing to after       dDict.Remove(kvp.Key)        is executed?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Ok, got it. So it would be pointing to a new memory, which holds a copy of kvp.Value?
BTW, how do I mark this question as answered?

Comment: MrCheese you can accept one of the existing answers by clicking the green V icon at the left side of the preferred answer, but currently there are no answers to your question. You can post a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you want.